# Problem Rasterize QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have a shapefile with one point (starting point of a rockfall) and want to rasterize this to do further calculations.

When I rasterize it into a Zero-Raster-File (called "startgrd", which is DEM*0), it gets me a new raster with only one value for all cells (0).

Do you know what might be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you tried using custom resolution or nrow/ncol? Or... Did you use base raster to set resolution?

Comment: @aldo_tapia I used custom resolution as well....using "Raster size in pixels", the +process crashes sometimes after starting successfully". Using Raster resolution in mao units per pixel with 1/1, it gets me one raster cell only. Actually I need to use base raster to set resolution as it should have the same size as the DEM raster...

Comment: Maybe your data isn't integer and QGIS don't set it properly. Try using `gdal_rasterize` from command line. Use the same syntax from bottom panel and add `-ot CFloat32` or `-ot CFloat64`.

Comment: my bad...I did not realise that I should change the layer style...it works pretty fine...thank you

Comment: @Kevin, I have a similar problem rasterizing a point layer; what do you mean by layer style?

Comment: @teresa in layer properties you can set the layer style. If I remembered the case correctly, all cell values were shown in the same style. see [this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html)